# JavaScript show text if no keydown events happen within 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, keydown

How do I show text if no keys are pressed in 3 seconds with JavaScript? Below is my code but it doesn't work.

```
var response_handler = function (e) {

    var keyCode = e.keyCode,
    response;
    switch (keyCode) {
            case 39:
                response = 'right';
                break;
            default:
                response = '';
                break;
        };
    if (response.length > 0) {
    d3.select('#text').html('you pressed right arrow!');
    }else {
    setTimeout(function () {
    d3.select('#text').html('you didn't press any key!');
    }, 3000);
  };

}
$("body").focus().keydown(response_handler);
```

Comment: Make your timeout global, and a separate function for your timeout. That way you can restart the timeout when a key is pressed and your handler isn't so cluttered. Also, you should start the timeout immediately. Use `setTimeout(functionName);` to use a separated function.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right.  :)

The `setTimeout` function return a handle, which can be used to `cancel` the timer when you no longer need it.

```
   var timer;

   var response_handler = function (e) {
          // for a better browser support
          var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
          if (keyCode == 39) {
                d3.select('#text').html('you pressed right arrow!');
          }
          if (timer) {
                // cancel existing timer if exist;
                clearTimeout(timer);
          }
          // setup a new timer (to extend another 3 sec)
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
                 d3.select('#text').html('you didn't press any key!');
          }, 3000);
   }
   $("body").focus().keydown(response_handler);
```

Once you're familiar with the basic, I'd recommend you to look into concept like `throttle` and `debounce`, which might be applicable to what you're trying to achieve, and there's a lot of utilities library/functions that simplify it up into a single function call for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are writing the `setTimeout` inside the `keydown` event. Do these

1. Make the `setTimeout` global and call it at `DOMReady`.
2. `cancelTimeout` when any key is pressed